# Do tools exist for creating Agile/scrum Story Maps in TFS?

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum

Is it possible to create a story map in my TFS board?

The answers I've seen to this question from other people do not meet my needs. Is there another option?

A [story map](http://jpattonassociates.com/the-new-backlog/) is a backlog arranged along two dimensions, instead of just one. Stories along the horizontal dimension are like epics or the highest level of stories that give an MVP. The items extending from each of the horizontal items are the refinement or extension of those high-level items.

A couple of options are presented in this forum discussion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1085bd92-c6b3-479c-a6a7-3464c8e8f60d/is-anyone-using-story-mapping-with-tfs?forum=tfsgeneral

One is a PowerPoint-TFS integration plug-in that gives visualization capabilities to TFS, but it's not specifically for story mapping.

The second is a third-party tool that is simply too expensive to be considered: http://www.speclog.net/.

Thank you.

Comment: I see that this was downvoted as being "off topic because This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center (link provided)". I suggest the downvoter actually _read_ the help center text (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which includes:**software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development** Both are clearly true in this case

Comment: It also says that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: The question I asked was: "Is there another option?" I showed my research and could not find more options. Also, the _intent_ of downvoting is to say that the asker just asked a question without putting any effort in or that the question would not be useful to anyone else. I would argue that this is absolutely useful to any serious Agile practitioner. On the other hand, being overly pedantic about SO rules is not useful to anyone

Comment: I edited the title to make it more wordily ask what it was asking before: it's a yes or no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, TFS has the User story mapping function, but it is not very same to that you described above. 
About the Agile/Scrum template in TFS, User Story/PBI could be mapped to **Feature**. Feature is the upper/parent level of User Story/PBI just like the MVP you mentioned above. About how to **map a User Story to a Feature**, please refer to this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/agile-process-workflow#map-user-stories-to-features.

Also in the Agile/Scrum template, Feature could also be mapped to an **Epic**. You could also add many **Tasks** as the children of a User Story. The relationship between them shows in the below picuture.
[image]

In TFS, it provides many boards for you to track your work items. You could know find the mapping relationship from those board. In the Feature backlog board, you could find which User Stories under this Feature, and so on.

[image]

**Note:** To learn more about Agile/Scrum in TFS, please refer to [the official document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/overview).

### **Update:**

As a workaround, you could use Excel to export those User stories and Features and do a story map. You could refer to this blog: http://jimbrissononagile.blogspot.sg/2014/12/story-mapping-for-tfs-using-excel.html

Here is an user voice about story mapping in TFS, you could vote or submit a new at this site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4130976-create-a-new-view-in-tfs-task-board-to-view-backlo

Comment: This is essential information for using TFS, but it's the standard way to use it. As you noted, this does not allow story maps along 2 dimensions

Comment: @stifin The 2 dimensions ways doesn't support in TFS, As a workaround, you could do story mapping use Excel. please refer to the update of my reply.

Answer (score 0):

We've recently published and extension for Story Mapping on TFS/VSTS: http://specmap.cc/

It's currently in preview and we're looking for feedback on it.